# How can I parse emails from git send-email?

Tags: git, email, git-send-email

Does anyone know of a system or library that can parse emails sent by [git send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email)?  So ideally receive emails and automatically create branches or PRs?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), "apply mail".

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that. But it's only part of the solution - you still need to connect to email, filter/parse them, etc.

Comment: Any mail service should support IMAP and POP3, and there's any number of email clients that speak that and will save in mailbox/maildir format. That part's got nothing to do with Git.

Answer (score -1):

Initial results:

[Patchwork](https://github.com/getpatchwork/patchwork)

- A web-based patch tracking system designed to facilitate the contribution and management of contributions to an open-source project.

[Patchwork](https://github.com/dlespiau/patchwork)

- The freedesktop.org edition of patchwork (a fork of the above).

[libgitmail](https://docs.rs/libgitmail)

- A Rust library that can parse git-send-email generated email.